# Cannot Create Array of Labels - Card Game, Python, Tinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I am still new to programming and I am trying to learn how to use the tkinter library. I am now trying to create an Array of Labels for my Cards that is generated upon user input. However, when I do, the GUI displays just one card. 
I have also tried using while- and larger for-loops to generate this, however no method seems to work. 
I'm pasting the portion of my code I cannot seem to work properly. 
If you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
    RowNum = self.REntry.get() #gets user input for rows
    ColumnNum = self.CEntry.get() #gets user input for columns
    RowNum = int(RowNum)
    ColumnNum = int(ColumnNum)

    self.clabel=  [[0 for x in range(ColumnNum)] for x in range(RowNum)] #creates an array that will hold the Labels
    for x in range(RowNum):
        for y in range(ColumnNum):
            card = self.deck.deal() #defined in another class, essentially pops the last item off of the deck
            self.frontofcard = PhotoImage(file = card.filename)
            self.clabel[x][y] = Label(self.CardsPane, image = self.frontofcard)
            self.clabel[x][y].grid(column=x, row=y)
```

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting the reference to fronofcard in the loop. Tkinter uses "weak references", so you need to make sure the photoimage gets stored as well as the label http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Comment: self.frontofcard is overwritten each time so it only contains the last image, i.e. there is only one self.frontofcard at any time and each label points to it.  You will have to save them in a list or some container, perhaps self.clabel[x][y] is a sublist containing the Label ID and the image.

Comment: Thank you both! I should have realized that tkinter blanked out their references each time. I looked into the link and was able to revise it based on that. The working code is now:

Comment: self.clabel=  [[0 for x in range(ColumnNum)] for x in range(RowNum)] 
            for x in range(RowNum):
                 for y in range(ColumnNum):
                    card = self.deck.deal()
                    photo = PhotoImage(file = card.filename)
                    self.clabel[x][y] = Label(self.CardsPane, image = photo)
                    self.clabel[x][y].image = photo
                    self.clabel[x][y].grid(column=x, row=y)